# How to secure the contents inside the scope of UIWebview in iPhone

Tags: ios, cookies, uiwebview, security, local-storage

To ellobrate my requirement, I'm have native iPhone application. In it i have UIWebview as part of my screen. This webview is loaded with an intranet web application link. which in turn have links to few more intranet applications. These web applications have cookie, cache, local storage data etc. These data are stored in my native application's sandbox file system. I would like to know how to make sure that these contents are secured wiht the application. The requirement is to double secure the content. Based on configuration i may be want to delete the information stored in the filesystem. To be in detail, i may be want to delete all the information from the intranet web application1 alone from the file system, leaving other data undisturbed.

Note: I may not be able to do any changes to the source of my intranet web applications.

kindly advise me on this.